# Trying to install glee-dev ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I tried install glee-dev using this simple procedure:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y glee-dev
```

But I received an error..."the package is not available" Any idea to solve?

```
(soccerpy3) pyboss:sudo apt-get install glee-dev 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
Package glee-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source 

E: Package 'glee-dev' has no installation candidate 
(soccerpy3) pyboss:
```

*here the output of "sudo apt update" updated, removed all artful repositories.

```
(soccerpy3) pyboss:sudo apt update 
[sudo] password for nbortolotti: 
Hit:1 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu disco InRelease 
Hit:2 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease 
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease 
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease 
Hit:5 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease 
Hit:6 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu disco-security InRelease 
Hit:7 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu disco-proposed InRelease 
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease 
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
All packages are up to date. 
(soccerpy3) pyboss:
```

*here all the info of "/etc/apt/sources.list"

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-security main restricted
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-security universe
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-security multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu/ disco-proposed multiverse main universe restricted #Not for humans during development stage of release bionic
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco main
```

Adding output of "apt show glee-dev"

```
(soccerpy3) pyboss:apt show glee-dev 
Package: glee-dev 
State: not a real package (virtual) 
N: Can't select candidate version from package glee-dev as it has no candidate 
N: Can't select versions from package 'glee-dev' as it is purely virtual 
N: No packages found 
(soccerpy3) pyboss:
```

Comment: I removed -y flags, and it is active universe-repository but... same error when I try to install.

Comment: @user535733 I added the information requested and also I replaced the error-picture for a english version.

Comment: ok @user535733 done!

Comment: I added  the output of  "apt show glee-dev" @user535733

Comment: Aha, found it: Glee was dropped from Ubuntu after 18.10 as it seems abandoned upstream. There is no glee, glee-dev, or libglee0g1, etc. packages in 19.04.

Comment: @NicolasBortolotti Thanks :) It makes it easier for others to read and google as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glee-dev has been discontinued, but you can install the glee-dev package from 18.10 in 19.04 by manually downloading [libglee0d1_5.4.0-2_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libglee0d1/download) and [glee-dev_5.4.0-2_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/glee-dev/download). Then open the terminal, change directories using `cd` to the directory containing libglee0d1_5.4.0-2_amd64.deb and glee-dev_5.4.0-2_amd64.deb, and run the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./libglee0d1_5.4.0-2_amd64.deb    
sudo apt install ./glee-dev_5.4.0-2_amd64.deb
```